# How to hide all layer except one in photoshop cs5.5?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I Only want to operate in one layer.
I want temporarily hide all other layers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Alt** click the layer's eye that you want to show and all the other ones will be hidden.

Clicking again with alt will invert the same action.

Comment: The issue here is that I have a million layers, some hidden and some visible. When I need my visibility back ALL layers become "eyed". Can we revert layer visibility status somehow?

Comment: @BenRacicot Yes you can. In the `Window > History` panel you'll find a corner menu ( Icon at the top right corner of the panel ). Click it and go to `History options...`. In there you will find a checkbox that makes layer visibility undoable. Once you enable it, you can use the method in my answer and revert back to prior state with `Ctrl+Z`.

Answer (score 4):

By checking layer eye on/off, this will hide layers one by one.

you can hide/unhide any layer in photoshop

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I appreciate you editing your answer to match my answer after you realized you didn't answer the actual question. So, I give you mental minus point and you have to live with that for the rest of your life.

Comment: hahahha lollero things cant be changed, what you know could be same with what i know, i am removing those lines which you think i tried to match with your answer...be happy you answered correctly :) lol @ your mental minus point

Comment: and that was just matter of time nothing else i dont need to match answers here, we should help our self and others here...and i was doing the same...

Comment: I saw it as matter of time too. You edited your answer to match mine 20 minutes after I had made my answer. So, in my mind you knew the same thing I knew, but 20 minutes after I told what I know and I'm paranoid... like the song...

Comment: @lovespring your welcome....@lollero i cant stop laughing on such responses from you, i thought you are sincere enough but no hard feelings :D peace \m/

Comment: That is one bumpy head. \m/ As usually people write \o/ which is a person throwing hands up in the air. For showing me the way of the bumpy head, I'm gonna give you +1.

Comment: @Lollero It's probably the [sign of the horns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_of_the_horns#Electronic_communication).

Comment: @DanielBeck Now that's just silly :)

Comment: @Lollero Damn, got me :-)

Comment: Thank you Jack for that amazing answer... So much better than all the others!